# issue on setting angular 4 on windows machine facing this error

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I am getting an error to install angular4 cli  with node & npm  on the windows machine. getting this error

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
>   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, this is a warning.

It says that the dependency `fsevents` wants a darwin operating system, but you are running on a Windows (win32 OS) machine.

It is only a warning because it is just an optional dependency for mac users.

The warning may disapear if you update NPM, though.

More details in [this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13935).